# Initializing distance array to 0 in Bellman Ford Algorithm

Tags: graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I am finding difficulty in understanding why the distance array is initialized to 0 in some problems while solving **Shortest Path** problems using **Bellman Ford** algorithm.

As per the algo, only the source vertex will be initialized to 0 and other vertices will be initialized with POSITIVE INFINITY.

However, i noticed that the below problem passed all testcases only when distance[] was initialized to 0 .

[Problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1197)

My code

```
// Link to this code: https://cses.fi/paste/03babebf2de8fff2298001/

//package com.graph;
 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 
public class CycleFinding {
 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        new CycleFinding().run();
    }
 
    public void run() throws Exception {
    
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        
        int n = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
        int m = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
        
        Edge[] edgeArr = new Edge[m];
        int idx = 0;
        while( idx < m ) {
            StringTokenizer edgeTokens = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int a = Integer.parseInt(edgeTokens.nextToken());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(edgeTokens.nextToken());
            double c = Double.parseDouble(edgeTokens.nextToken());
 
            Edge edge = new Edge(a, b, c);
            edgeArr[idx++] = edge;          
        }
        detectCycle(n, m, edgeArr);
        out.flush();
    }
 
    public void detectCycle( int n , int m , Edge[] edgeArr ) {
        
        double[] distance = new double[n+1];
//      Arrays.fill(distance, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        int[] parent = new int[n+1];
        Arrays.fill(parent, -1);
        
        int src =3;
        distance[src] = 0;
        
        int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(Edge edge : edgeArr) {
                if( distance[edge.to] > distance[edge.from] + edge.length ) {
                    distance[edge.to] = distance[edge.from] + edge.length; 
                    parent[edge.to] = edge.from;
                    x = edge.to;
                }
            }
        }
 
        if( x == Integer.MIN_VALUE ) {
            out.println("NO");
        }else {
            
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                x =parent[x];
        
            ArrayList<Integer> cycle = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int v = x;; v = parent[v])
            {
               cycle.add(v);
               if (v == x && cycle.size() > 1)
                        break;
            }
                // Reverse cycle[]
            Collections.reverse(cycle);
            out.println("YES");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int v : cycle) {
                builder.append(v);
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            out.println(builder.toString());
        }       
    }
    
    public List<Integer> printCycle(double[] distance){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                
        
        return list;
    }
    
    
 static class Edge{
     int from;
     int to;
     double length;
 
     public Edge(int from, int to, double length) {
         this.from = from;
         this.to = to;
         this.length = length;
     }
 }
}
```

After searching online I have found out that, distance[] should be initialized to 0 in the following cases

- When Multi Source Shortest Path is reqd.
- Disconnected graphs.
- Negative edge self loop/cycle (based on observation of a testcase in
  above mentioned problem)

Kindly help me understand, when to initialize the distance array with 0 and when with INFINITY.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a multisource Bellman-Ford case. This is due to the graph may not reach a negative cycle if we run the algorithm over a particular source (the graph may not be connected or just there is no directed path to the negative cycles from that source).
You can also find this approach in some text as creating a new source and connecting all the nodes with edges with weight zero. If a negative cycle exists this will be detected after running the classic Bellman-Ford from the new source.

In fact, you can initialize all the distances with any value but all the nodes should have the same initial distance.